# Placing a ceramic bowl over stainless steel saucepan

Tags: cookware, custard, stainless-steel, ceramic

I have a few ceramic bowls that are oven, microwave, and dishwasher safe (I normally hand-wash them, though). I was looking at recipes for lemon curd and some of them recommended putting them in a metal bowl over a saucepan that has steaming water in it. Is it possible to instead use a ceramic bowl? It would not touch the water below, only along the rim of the saucepan.

Would this be bad for the bowl? I can deal with a few aesthetic scratches and scuffs on the side.

Will this take a lot longer to heat up?

Comment: I feel that it'd be too insulated to work properly... it's a double-boiler and you need a good amount of heat or it won't thicken... or all of the timing the recipe gave would be off significantly. Is there a particular reason you want to use ceramic instead of metal?

Comment: I'm just cheap and don't want to buy new cookware if I don't have to. I also live in NYC, so space is limited.

Comment: Let it preheat for a few minutes and it should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will take longer to heat than a thin metal bowl. It probably wouldn't crack, being oven-safe - it's just being exposed to steam, not direct flame, so long as it is above the water, not sitting on the bottom of the pot (which is what you describe.)